# knockout js in Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, knockoutjs

How to use knockout js in Magento 2 admin sales order creation?

I did the same way like frontend but my code is not working.

Kindly help me, if you have used knockout js for admin.

Comment: Please provide more details like your code which you have done.